# Custom UserSessionRegistry in Spring web socket implementation for a multi tenant scenario?

Tags: spring-websocket

I am working with Spring Websocket (4.1.4 release) and using @SendToUser for sending messages to the current user. But I've a problem. Ours is a multi-tenant platform where username is not unique, instead a combination of username and tenant id is unique. The `DefaultUserSessionRegistry` keeps a map from username to a list of session ids:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Set<String>> userSessionIds = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

which would not work in my scenario. So is there a way I can plugin my custom `UserSessionRegistry` implementation?

Answer (score 2):

After a code search, the issue seems related to this [line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/fbd85925de74ea02dbf3dbe521743097e6b3356b/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.java#L327).
I found that this class is extended by WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport, which is extended by a @Configuration class (DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration), so you could try to extend it by yourself, like in this example:

https://github.com/arawn/overview-of-spring4/blob/master/src/main/java/jco/conference/oxquiz/WebSocketConfig.java

I had no time to verify this, but if your problem is only the UserSessionRegistry implementation, this could be the way of overriding that @Bean method.

Update:

After digging a bit more, I found the real entry point to the whole flow: search for the DefaultHandshakeHandler class, having the determineUser method (I cannot add more links because of my low score)